# Django-nonrel form field for ListField

Tags: google-app-engine, django-admin, django-nonrel, listfield

I'm experimenting with `django-nonrel` on appengine and trying to use a `djangotoolbox.fields.ListField` to implement a many-to-many relation. As I read in the documentation a `ListField` is something that you can use to make a workaround for djamgo-nonrel not supporting many-to-many relations.

This is an excerpt from my model:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    field = ListField(models.ForeignKey(AnotherClass))
```

So if I am getting this right I am creating a list of foreign keys to another class to show a relationship with multiple instances of another class

With this approach everything works fine ... No Exceptions. I can create `MyClass' objects in code and views. But when I try to use the admin interface I get the following error

```
No form field implemented for <class 'djangotoolbox.fields.ListField'>
```

So I though I would try something that I haven't done before. Create my own field. Well actually my own form for editing `MyClass` instances in the admin interface. Here is what I did:

```
class MyClassForm(ModelForm):
    field = fields.MultipleChoiceField(choices=AnotherClass.objects.all(), widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("verbose_name", is_stacked=False))
    class Meta:
        model = MyClass
```

then I pass `MyClassForm` as the form to use to the admin interface

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyClassForm

admin.site.register(MyClass, MyClassAdmin)
```

I though that this would work but It doesn't. When I go to the admin interface I get the same error as before. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong here ... or if you have any other suggestions or success stories of using the `ListField`, `SetField`, etc. from `djangotoolbox.fields` in the admin interface it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, here is what I did to get this all working ...
I'll start from the beginning

This is what what my model looked like

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    field = ListField(models.ForeignKey(AnotherClass))
```

I wanted to be able to use the admin interface to create/edit instances of this model using a multiple select widget for the list field. Therefore, I created some custom classes as follows

```
class ModelListField(ListField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return FormListField(**kwargs)

class ListFieldWidget(SelectMultiple):
    pass

class FormListField(MultipleChoiceField):
    """
    This is a custom form field that can display a ModelListField as a Multiple Select GUI element.
    """
    widget = ListFieldWidget

    def clean(self, value):
        #TODO: clean your data in whatever way is correct in your case and return cleaned data instead of just the value
        return value
```

These classes allow the listfield to be used in the admin. Then I created a form to use in the admin site

```
class MyClassForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClasstForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field'].widget.choices = [(i.pk, i) for i in AnotherClass.objects.all()]
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['field'].initial = self.instance.field

    class Meta:
        model = MyClass
```

After having done this I created a admin model and registered it with the admin site

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyClassForm

    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        super(MyClassAdmin,self).__init__(model, admin_site)

admin.site.register(MyClass, MyClassAdmin)
```

This is now working in my code. Keep in mind that this approach might not at all be well suited for google_appengine as I am not very adept at how it works and it might create inefficient queries an such.

Comment: Rman, I am having issues implementing the above example, can you post your input at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782535/django-nonrel-with-mongdb-listfield

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you're trying to have a M2M relationship in django-nonrel, which is not an out-of-the-box functionality. For starters, if you want a quick hack, you can go with this simple class and use a `CharField` to enter foreign keys manually:

```
class ListFormField(forms.Field):
    """ A form field for being able to display a djangotoolbox.fields.ListField. """

    widget = ListWidget

    def clean(self, value):
        return [v.strip() for v in value.split(',') if len(v.strip()) > 0]
```

But if you want to have a multiple selection from a list of models normally you'd have to use ModelMultipleChoiceField, which is also not functional in django-nonrel. Here's what I've done to emulate a M2M relationship using a MultipleSelectField:

Let's say you have a M2M relationship between 2 classes, SomeClass and AnotherClass respectively. You want to select the relationship on the form for SomeClass. Also I assume you want to hold the references as a ListField in SomeClass. (Naturally you want to create M2M relationships as they're explained [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16952419/Building-scalable-complex-apps-on-App-Engine), to prevent exploding indexes if you're working on App Engine).

So you have your models like:

```
class SomeClass(models.Model):
    another_class_ids = ListField(models.PositiveIntegerField(), null=True, blank=True)
    #fields go here

class AnotherClass(models.Model):
    #fields go here
```

And in your form:

```
class SomeClassForm(forms.ModelForm):

    #Empty field, will be populated after form is initialized
    #Otherwise selection list is not refreshed after new entities are created.
    another_class = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SomeClassForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['another_class'].choices = [(item.pk,item) for item in AnotherClass.objects.all()]

    if self.instance.pk: #If class is saved, highlight the instances that are related
        self.fields['another_class'].initial = self.instance.another_class_ids

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  
    self.instance.another_class_ids = self.cleaned_data['another_class']         
    return super(SomeClassForm, self).save()

class Meta:
    model = SomeClass
```

Hopefully this should get you going for the start, I implemented this functionality for normal forms, adjust it for admin panel shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. It helped me figure out how to get to what I need. I can now display a `ListField` as a `SelectMultiple` in my own forms. I still have to do some extra work to get this working in the admin pages

Comment: Could you explain what work needs to be done to get this working in the admin pages?

Answer (score 0):

This could be unrelated but for the admin interface, be sure you have djangotoolbox listed after django.contrib.admin in the settings.. INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid a custom form class for such usage by inquiring for the model object

```
class ModelListField(ListField):
  def __init__(self, embedded_model=None, *args, **kwargs):
  super(ModelListField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  self._model = embedded_model.embedded_model

  def formfield(self, **kwargs):
    return FormListField(model=self._model, **kwargs)

class ListFieldWidget(SelectMultiple):
  pass

class FormListField(MultipleChoiceField):
  widget = ListFieldWidget

  def __init__(self, model=None, *args, **kwargs):
    self._model = model
    super(FormListField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.widget.choices = [(unicode(i.pk), i) for i in self._model.objects.all()]

  def to_python(self, value):
    return [self._model.objects.get(pk=key) for key in value]

  def clean(self, value):
    return value
```