# Unable to save django-toolbox ListField to database using django admin view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-nonrel

I am writing a django-nonrel based app and using admin view functionality provided by Django.

I want a `Many-to-many relationship` between two models and for this, I am using `ListField` found inside `djangotoolbox.fields`

To provide a custom form field, I have overridden ListField with another class ModelListField as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7782535/333137) which overrides formfield function to return a MultipleChoiceField form widget.

*The view part works fine but I am unable to save the model using sqlite3 backend.*

Assume, two models (Standard Many-to-many relationship between note and tags)

```
from django.db import models

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Note(models.Model):
    tags = ModelListField(db.ForeignKey(Tag))
```

With these change, add note page appears correctly in admin interface but when I try to save the note, I get the following exception:

```
InterfaceError, Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.  
inside django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 234
```

The line 234 reads as follows:

```
class SQLiteCursorWrapper(Database.Cursor):
    """
    Django uses "format" style placeholders, but pysqlite2 uses "qmark" style.
    This fixes it -- but note that if you want to use a literal "%s" in a query,
    you'll need to use "%%s".
    """
    def execute(self, query, params=()):
        query = self.convert_query(query)
        try:
234 ---->           return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
        except Database.IntegrityError, e:
            raise utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e)), sys.exc_info()[2]
        except Database.DatabaseError, e:
            raise utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e)), sys.exc_info()[2]
```

And query & params passed to call are:

```
query: 'INSERT INTO "note" ("tags") VALUES (?)'  
params: [1, 2, 3]
where 1, 2, 3 are pk of three tag fields in database.
```

When creating model, I specify the COLUMN TYPE of tags as "ListField" i.e.
CREATE table SQL query is:

```
CREATE TABLE "notes" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "tags" ListField NOT NULL
)
```

Database query execute call above barfs when it sees the list [1,2,3].
Instead of list, I tried to pass the list as `smart_unicode(list)` or just a string `"1 2 3"` but then `ListField` throws error while validating (in get_db_prep_value) because it expects list.

*I am unable to understand whether it is correct to pass the list object to `Database.Cursor.execute` call above or something is missing as ListField is correctly expecting list but when writing to database, someone should have converted this list into string etc..?*

There's no good example of how to use ListField :-(
Thanks for reading a long & boring description..

Comment: You're using django-nonrel with SQLite as a backend?  That's weird.  You should be using django, not django-nonrel.

Comment: I am changing a django app for django-nonrel which will be used with a different backend.. I will change the backend soon but i dont think there's any non-compatible issues between django-nonrel and sqlite.

Comment: ListFields don't map to anything on an sqlite backend.  So your problem is django-nonrel is not compatible with sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it is the responsibility of get_db_prep_save to prepare data in correct format for saving to database.
So, in ModelListField, I override get_db_prep_save and convert it to string to fix the "Unsupported type" error.

```
def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection):
    retval = super(ModelListField, self).get_db_prep_save(value)
    return unicode(retval)
```

I also faced an issue with Select Widget not showing tags with pk > 10 as selected.
Inside django-non 1.3, 
I had to add eval in below function:

```
class Select(Widget):
    def render_options(self, choices, selected_choices):
        **if(type(selected_choices) != list):
            selected_choices = eval(selected_choices)**
```

This was done because render_option was called with list as string i.e. "[1,2,3]" instead of just [1,2,3], so string was converted back to list using eval.
Not sure if these two are related or latter issue is bug with django-nonrel.

As dragonx said, maybe it's not a good idea to test with sqlite3 and django-nonrel.
I will change my backend soon.